# How to install multiple versions of the same node.js module?

Tags: node.js, npm

Can I install multiple versions of the same `node` module globally with `npm`?

Comment: You might be able to use a version manager for Node to facilitate this: https://github.com/isaacs/nave

Comment: And how would you deal w/ it ? Require it? Run it?

Comment: @Freyday, https://github.com/isaacs/nave is interesting to know of, but appears to me to allow easy swapping (and combining?) of ‘multiple versions of’ _nodejs_, NOT what the Q asked for: of ‘node _module_'s, and here ‘globally with npm'. So is it you missed the Q's ‘module’ part? Or if no, please detail the solution you're seeing (I want solutions for this, too), ideally as its own answer to this Q including in Wiki mode if the answer might be helped by others editing as extending it, too. Thanks.

Comment: @DestinyArchitect I have posted an answer to this question, but it probably isn't worth the hassle of keeping it working as node, npm or the modules in question are updated. Your milage may vary.

Comment: npm i <custom_package_name>@npm:<package_name>

Answer (score 5):

I don't think there is a (good) way to do this.

However, I'm guessing that your use case is this: You have two projects, which require different versions of a globally installed package.

For cases like this, I usually avoid installing packages globally altogether, and install them locally instead (without `-g`). For example, if you wanted to install a specific older version of the "mocha" package for a given project, you'd do

```
cd ~/src/myproject
npm install --save-dev mocha@^1.0.0
```

(Note that we're not using `-g` here.) Then call it like so:

```
./node_modules/.bin/mocha
```

Answer (score 2):

While it is possible, it's probably going to be difficult to maintain without writing your own scripts to manage it. For this, I'm going to assume that you are using MacOS or Linux, and you have node installed in `/usr/local/bin`

When you install a global module, npm places the module and its dependencies in the same location that node is installed. Usually `/usr/local/lib/node_modules`, then creates a symbolic link for that module's in `/usr/local/bin`.

For example, you want to install nodemon, so you run `npm install -g nodemon`. npm installs nodemon to `/usr/local/lib/node_modules/nodemon` and creates a symlink at `/usr/local/bin/nodemon` that points to `/usr/local/lib/node_modules/nodemon/bin/nodemon.js`

Lets assume that you just installed nodemon@1.8.1, but for some reason you also need nodemon@1.7.3.

To have them both installed at once, but not conflict, you may be able to:

1. rename the directory for your existing copy of nodemon from `nodemon` to `nodemon18`
2. create a new `nodemon18` symlink using `ln -s /usr/local/bin/nodemon18 /usr/local/lib/node_modules/nodemon/bin/nodemon.js` (don't forget to make it executable)
3. install nodemon@1.7.3 via `npm install -g nodemon@1.7.3`

Now, running `nodemon` from your terminal will run nodemon@1.7.3 and running `nodemon18` will run nodemon@1.8.1.

**YMMV. I really don't recommend doing this.**

Answer (score 1):

Not currently.

(Related: You can install multiple versions of node using with NVM (Node Version Manager): https://github.com/creationix/nvm)

Comment: I think the question being asked was about installing multiple versions of a particular node module. Isn't NVM designed to let you install multiple versions of the Node runtime?